# mysql need assistance of the customers who live in a state that borders Ohio

Tags: mysql

"Retrieve all of the customers who live in a state that borders Ohio.  (Those states include IN, KY, MI, PA, and WV and you may use this info in your query)".

Im not sure how to complete it the query, this is what i have so far

mysql> select cust_state from customers group by cust_state

Comment: Please go for a mysql beginners' tutorial.

Comment: ditch the GROUP BY. And add a WHERE clause.  `cust_state IN ('IN','KY','MI',...)`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the IN statement in your WHERE clause to retrieve all your customers:

```
SELECT cust_state FROM customers WHERE cust_state IN ('IN','KY','MI','PA','WV')
```

More documentation on the IN operator:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in